# How to cancel bluetooth's passkey dialog

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am pairing to a remote bluetooth device while pairing I am asked to to confirm the passkey via a dialog..

my question is how to cancel the passkey dialog? i want to pair without being asked to confirm the passkey

**image**:

[image]